# Is it worthy to minimize the count of draw call by setting up an addition per-vertex attribute used as object index?

Tags: opengl, graphics, directx, vulkan

I am trying to organize draw call for my scene asset with many materials and meshes. The strategy I thought:

- Each kind of material need a seperate draw call
- Same mesh with different transformations can be grouped into one draw call with multiple instance data to pass the transformations

However, there are so many different meshes with different `dynamic transformations`, thus they are **not able to be organize into one instance draw call**. Instead, each mesh with different dynamic transformation need a draw call, resuling into a number of draw calls.

- `dynamic transformation`: the translation, rotation and scale of a mesh are updated per frame

If I use **a storage buffer to save each mesh's transformation** and use the unique `object index` of mesh to index into the storage buffer, getting corresponding transformations. But the object index can not be instanced, because the meshes with different dynamic transformations can not be instanced. Therefore, an additional vertex attribute is required for each vertex for implementing the method. At the same time, it will occupy some memeory usage for redundancy primitive index data, because the primitive index of one mesh is same.

- `object index`: an index assigned to a mesh, which can be used to index into storage buffer for getting the transformation of the mesh.
- `the reason why object index should be per vertex`: each mesh only need one object index, but I can not pass the mesh's object index per mesh/instance. Because I want to group meshes with different transformations into one draw call and these different meshes can not be instanced in one draw call, thus the object index data can not be passed by instance data.

Is it worthy to implement this method? Or is there a more practical way to minimize the count of draw call?

Comment: What is a "dynamic transformation" and how is this separate from other transformations? Also, what is a "primitive index"; do you really want to have an index for each individual triangle? Or does "unique primitive index of mesh" mean an index for each draw call?

Comment: "*primitive index: an index assigned to a mesh,  which can be used to index into storage buffer for getting the transformation of the mesh.*" Then it's not a *primitive* index. The word "primitive" has a [specific meaning in the context of rendering systems](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Primitive), and this isn't it. The kind of thing you're talking about is more of an object index.

Comment: @NicolBolas Thanks for pointing out the ambiguity. I updated my question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So you have a number of objects you want to draw. Some of those objects use different meshes from different objects, but sometimes they share the same underlying mesh. But regardless, a particular collection of objects all share the same vertex format and source buffers (VAO), as well as the same shader logic and shader resources.

But these objects do have different, per-object information. This is what distinguishes each object within such a collection. You cite transform information, but really, it could be all kinds of per-object state (textures, etc).

And your goal is to draw all of the objects in a collection with a single draw call. So you need a way to distinguish between different objects in the shader, as well as a way to use those distinct.

What you ultimately need is to give each object an index and provide an array to the shader that the shader will use to fetch that index and get its per-object information. All vertices for a particular object need to get the same index, and if two different objects draw from the same mesh, the shaders for those two objects need different indices.

This is what multi-draw and `gl_DrawID` are for. `gl_DrawID` is core in GL 4.6, but it was available as the extension `ARB_shader_draw_parameters` for some time before being adopted into core. It's [pretty widely available](http://opengl.gpuinfo.org/listreports.php?extension=GL_ARB_shader_draw_parameters).

[Multi-draw rendering commands](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Vertex_Rendering#Multi-Draw) allow you to issue multiple draw calls with a single function call. These draw calls all have to use the same primitive type, but you already had that limitation before, so that's no problem. Each draw in the array of drawing commands is executed in order, first to last.

As such, each draw has an index, from 0 to the number of draws. You can access this index in a vertex shader via the [`gl_DrawID` predefined input](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Vertex_Shader#Other_inputs). You can therefore use this index to fetch from your per-object SSBO array(s) to get whatever per-object information you want.

Plus, `gl_DrawID`, and any subsequent derivatives thereof, is always a [dynamically uniform expression](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Core_Language_(GLSL)#Dynamically_uniform_expression). As such, if you have an array of SSBOs (not an array *within* an SSBO; an array *of* SSBOs), array of sampler uniforms, or an array of [bindless textures](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Bindless_Texture), you can use `gl_DrawID` or some (dynamically uniform) expression based on it to access such arrays. So you can switch textures with this index.

So what happens to instancing in this process? While multi-draw indirect does in fact allow each draw to have its own instance count and base instance, instancing makes accessing per-object information much more complicated. Each draw index originally only used one piece of per-object information, so every draw command could just directly use its own index. But if a draw command can consume multiple pieces of per-object data, then each draw command has to know how many instances were consumed by previous draw commands.

That's not too difficult to do, actually, and shader_draw_parameters contains the solution: `gl_BaseInstance`. A multi-draw indirect command has both an instance count and a base instance value. The instance count maps directly to the `gl_InstanceID` field, but the base instance value is not added to this. Instead, you can access it directly with `gl_BaseInstance`.

You can calculate a particular index by taking advantage of this. The base instance value for each draw in the multi-draw command needs to be the sum total of all instance counts of prior drawing commands (including the ones that only draw 1 instance). Therefore, your per-object index is no longer `gl_DrawID`; it is `gl_BaseInstance + gl_InstanceID`.

*However*, if you do this, you lose the advantages of `gl_DrawID` being dynamically uniform. `gl_InstanceID` and `gl_BaseInstance` are not required to be dynamically uniform, so you're unable to use them to index arrays of SSBOs or samplers or even bindless textures. So if you want to switch textures based on the draw call, you're limited to using array textures.

Comment: Thanks for your clearly restatement. Using indirect draw commands to issue a batch of draw calls seems to be a practical way to minimize the count of draw calls. I mistaked the meaning of reducing draw call for reducing the number of executions of graphics pipeline. Reducing draw call should refer to the number of graphics API call, is it right?

Comment: @wangsy: No. You really should [watch this presentation,](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-bCeNzgiJ8I) particularly the last half.

Comment: Thanks for the recommended information. I have roughly read the slides of the talk. In my understanding, what I want to minimize is the number of changing pipeline state for my draw calls, because each kind of state change will bring some cost.